# Spring Cloud Bus support for Google CloudPubSub

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-bus

Do we have Google CloudPubSub support roadmap for Spring CloudBus for broadcasting state changes?

Comment: the bus uses spring-cloud-stream for implementations. It should be possible with https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-stream-binder

Comment: Thanks . We got it worked through Spring Cloud  Stream implementation